# Java GUI: Getting text from a textfield

Tags: java, sql, swing, user-interface

Hello i got blank display in the "Sale Cost" Textfield when i input a text in the "Item Price" TextField. i want to display the text that i input in the "Item Price" Textfield and will display in the "Sale Cost" Textfield which it didn't show.

[image]

```
public class ZipTimer extends JFrame {
    private JTextField input_2;
    private JTextField itemprice;

btnInsert = new JButton("Insert");
    btnInsert.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(new DBUpdater().add(itemname.getText(),itemprice.getText(),itemcategory.getText())){

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Successfully Inserted");

                //Clear Text                    
                itemprice.setText("");      
                input_2.setText(itemprice.getText());
                retrieve();
            }else{

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not Saved");
            }

        }
    });
```

the name of the Textfield in Sale Cost is `input_2`
and the name of Textfield in Item Price is `itemprice`

i try the other code which is this `input_2.setText(Integer.toString(itemprice));` but i have an error in `toString`i dont know why. it says "The method `toString`(int) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (JTextField)".

Comment: Have you tried [`itemprice.getText()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText--)?

Comment: Also, where is `itemprice` initialized? If not initialized, this code would throw a NullPointerException (npe). Are you seeing this? Same for `input_2` (terrible variable names -- please improve). Please create and post a valid [mcve].

Comment: itemprice is a text field, not an integer? Exception is self explanatory

Comment: i created a mysql database @HovercraftFullOfEels in my JFrame which you see in the image i attach here in my JTable.

Comment: yes @bradimus but i didn't work.

Comment: i just have problem in the line @HovercraftFullofEels someone answer and it now works..

Comment: i got wrong in using integer @cricket_007 now it works..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to turn these two lines around as the first one clears the text and the second one gets that cleared text.

Wrong:

```
itemprice.setText("");      
input_2.setText(itemprice.getText());
```

Correct:

```
input_2.setText(itemprice.getText());
itemprice.setText("");
```